# How to join a table with array(set?) in sql?

Tags: sql

I have an array of ids from external source, how do I filter the table with where clause, like:

```
select * from history where entry_id in [45,234,435]
```

How do I do that in Oracle SQL?

Comment: just chagne [] on ()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from history where entry_id in (45,234,435)
```

Comment: Parentheses instead of brackets! Thank you.